# Chart.js timescale: set min and max on xAxes

Tags: javascript, chart.js

How can I set a min and max on the `xAxes`? It works fine on the `yAxes` but on the `xAxes` it shows no behavior.

My `xAxes` is using the `type: 'time'`. My labels for the `xAxis` are using the `moment` object aswell. But it also does not work when I remove the type time and use normal digits. I am using the Chart.js version 2.2.2.

```
scales: {
   yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
         beginAtZero:false,
      }
   }],
   xAxes: [{
      type: 'time',
      ticks: {
         min: moment(1471174953000),
         max: moment(1473853353000)
      }   
   }]
}
```

[Here is the chart.js Time Scale documentation.](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-time-units)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The properties you are looking for actually are in the `time` attribute :

```js
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: "time",
            time: {
                min: 1471174953000,
                max: 1473853353000
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working for me. I am just wondering why I can place the min/max in the ticks attribute of the yAxes.

Comment: @Steckdoserich I don't know either, this is how it is built-in. I guess it is useful if you have several xAxes

Comment: Okay. In addition, is there a way to cut off the overlapping graph? Right now the graph is going over the yAxes.

Comment: @Steckdoserich I have the same problem, even if I'm not using a time type chart. I suppose it has already been reported on the [Github project](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues) but it hasn't been corrected yet.

Comment: @Steckdoserich Check the plugin I made for [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39536877/how-do-i-hide-values-past-the-x-axis-in-chartjs-2-0) which has the problem you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just found this plugin: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3329 a few hours ago, which works for me.

Comment: @Steckdoserich Oh great, didn't know this one. Thanks for linking it

Comment: @tektiv Oh my god, you saved me from 1 hour of research. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This was changed in 3.0

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/v3-migration.html#options

```js
scales.[x/y]Axes.time.max was renamed to scales[id].max
scales.[x/y]Axes.time.min was renamed to scales[id].min
```