# How do I hide values past the x-axis in chartjs 2.0?

Tags: chart.js

How do I hide values past the x-axis in chartjs 2.0? You will notice the chart juts past the -60 mark. The x-axis uses a time scale and I have the max and min values set.

[image]

Here's my chart configuration:

```
{  
   "type":"line",
   "data":{  
      "datasets":[  
         {  
            "label":"Scatter Dataset",
            "data":[  
               {  
                  "x":"2016-09-16T16:36:53Z",
                  "y":88.46153846153845
               },
               ...
               {  
                  "x":"2016-09-16T16:37:54Z",
                  "y":88.3076923076923
               }
            ],
            "pointRadius":0,
            "backgroundColor":"rgba(0,0,255,0.5)",
            "borderColor":"rgba(0,0,255,0.7)"
         }
      ]
   },
   "options":{  
      "title":{  
         "display":true,
         "text":"Water Level Over Last 60 Seconds"
      },
      "animation":false,
      "scales":{  
         "xAxes":[  
            {  
               "type":"time",
               "position":"bottom",
               "display":true,
               "time":{  
                  "max":"2016-09-16T16:37:54Z",
                  "min":"2016-09-16T16:36:54.000Z",
                  "unit":"second",
                  "unitStepSize":5
               },
               "ticks":{  
                        callback: function(value, index, values) {
                            return "-" + (60 - 5 * index);
                        }
               }
            }
         ],
         "yAxes":[  
            {  
               "display":true,
               "ticks":{  

               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "legend":{  
         "display":false
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using [Chart.js plugins](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-creating-plugins). They let you handle events occuring while creating, updating or drawing the chart.

Here, you'll need to affect before the chart is initialised :

```js
// We first create the plugin
var cleanOutPlugin = {

    // We affect the `beforeInit` event
    beforeInit: function(chart) {

        // Replace `ticks.min` by `time.min` if it is a time-type chart
        var min = chart.config.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.min;
        // Same here with `ticks.max`
        var max = chart.config.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.max;

        var ticks = chart.config.data.labels;
        var idxMin = ticks.indexOf(min);
        var idxMax = ticks.indexOf(max);

        // If one of the indexes doesn't exist, it is going to bug
        // So we better stop the program until it goes further
        if (idxMin == -1 || idxMax == -1)
            return;

        var data = chart.config.data.datasets[0].data;

        // We remove the data and the labels that shouldn't be on the graph
        data.splice(idxMax + 1, ticks.length - idxMax);
        data.splice(0, idxMin);
        ticks.splice(idxMax + 1, ticks.length - idxMax);
        ticks.splice(0, idxMin);
    }
};

// We now register the plugin to the chart's plugin service to activate it
Chart.pluginService.register(cleanOutPlugin);
```

---

The plugin is basically a loop through the data to remove the values that shouldn't be displayed.

You can see this plugin working in a [live example on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gyotsv07/).

For instance, the following chat with a min set to `2` and a max to `6` ...

[image]

... would give the following result :

[image]