# Create ticks at certain time positions on a chartjs cartesian time axis

Tags: javascript, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I created a realtime chart that updates about every 10 seconds by adding a new value and removing an old one.

[image: Image of the realtime chart]

I'm a bit unhappy about the chosen ticks of the time axis. Every 10 Minutes is fine, but I'd prefer values like `15:50`,`16:00`,`16:10`. I looked around the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html) time axis but did not find anything promising. 
My definition of my `xAxes` looks like:

```
    xAxes: [
        {
          gridLines: {
            display: true
          },
          type: "time",
          time: {
            unit: "minute",
            unitStepSize: 10,
            displayFormats: {
              minute: "HH:mm"
            }
          },
          ticks: {
            min: 0,
            max: this.datapoints.length,
            autoSkip: true,
            maxTicksLimit: 10
          }
        }
      ]
```

I tried to loop over the dataset and find the 'first pretty time' object and set this object as my `ticks.min` object. But this did not work.

Answer (score 1):

OK I found it. The property is in the `time` attribute:

```
time: {
  unit: "minute",
  unitStepSize: 10,
  displayFormats: {
    minute: "HH:mm"
  },
  min: firstprettyTime, // <- moment js object
},
```

All praise to this [guy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39535213/4634044).