# chartjs : uncaught exception: 0 and X are too far apart with stepSize of Y

Tags: chart.js

I am plotting data on a graph with chartjs. It used to work but I don't know why I am continuously getting `uncaught exception: 0 and 1587533402000 are too far apart with stepSize of 1 hour`, although neither 0 nor 1587533402000 are part of the data I plot.

Here is how I plot the graph :

```
var chart_temperature = new Chart(ctx_temperature, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'line',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
        labels: timeXValues,
        fill: false, // no inner color
        datasets: [{
                label: 'Temperature',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                data: temperatureData
            }]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        layout: {
            padding: {
                bottom: 50
            }
        },
        elements: {
            point: {
                radius: 0 // don't show points
            },
            line: {
                fill: false
            }
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        unit: 'hour',
                        displayFormats: {
                            hour: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'
                        }
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: false // tried true, and also removed all this as it used to be
                    }

                }],
            yAxes: [{
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'T°C'
                    }
                }]

        },
        showLines: true, // the points will be connected
        // Optimization
        animation: {
            duration: 0 // general animation time
        },
        hover: {
            animationDuration: 0 // duration of animations when hovering an item
        },
        responsiveAnimationDuration: 0 // animation duration after a resize

    }
});
```

Why is chartjs using 0 whereas the chart is not starting at 0 ? Where should I look at ?

Any help appreciated :-)

**Edit :**

Commenting the following line (in `scales.xAxes`) makes the chart displayed :

```
//                        type: 'time',
```

But the X Axis becomes then useless since timestamps are displayed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A genius idea finally spurted! Searching against `are too far apart with stepSize` [in chartjs git repository](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/search?q=are%20too%20far%20apart%20with%20stepSize%20of&unscoped_q=are%20too%20far%20apart%20with%20stepSize%20of) showed that time scale min option was wrongly set to 0.
Adding [these min max to time option of xAxes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39535213/6351897) solved the issue.

And even as time min max options are deprecated, `ticks.min` and `ticks.max` should be used:

```
ticks: {
    min: startTimestamp,
    max: endTimestamp
}
```

Comment: you should accept your answer as accepted, it helped solve my issue too!

Comment: @Junia Montana glad that helped you. It appears already as accepted when I am logged in.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I needed to update my type time to "minute" instead of "second".

```
 xAxes: [ {
          type: 'time',
          time: {
            unit: 'minute'
          },
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, that because the data from x is not 'int' but 'string'.

data from Backend:

```
data: [{
    x: "1626414792000",  //1626414792000
    y: 2
  }, {
    x: 1626414873000,  // 14:00:00
    y: 3
  }, {
    x: 1626415500000,  // 13:00:00
    y: 5
  }]
}],
```

Then, I parse x data before chart.js use it.
My full code:

```
var obj = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'First dataset',
      data: [{
        x: "1626414792000",
        y: 2
      }, {
        x: 1626414873000,
        y: 3
      }, {
        x: 1626415500000,
        y: 5
      }]
    }],
  },
  options: {
    title: {
        text: 'Chart',
        display: true,
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
            unit: 'minute',
            /* parsing x data before chart.js use it  */
            parser: function(dt){
                console.log(dt)
                return parseInt(dt);
            }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue happened when **zooming**.

It was caused by wrong properties of the `zoom` `plugin` `option` used with a chart type `'time'`. The following works options works fine:

```
options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          suggestedMin: 0,
        },
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'day',
          tooltipFormat: 'MMM DD YYYY',
        },
      }],
    },
    plugins: {
      zoom: {
        pan: {
          enabled: true,
          mode: 'xy'
        },
        zoom: {
          enabled: true,
          mode: 'xy',
        }
      }
    }
}
```